# trying to identify why Blender 3.0 crashes constantly (guidance appreciated)

Tags: workflow, error

0 in Windows 10.

I tried to find out what to do to find out what it is. The only thing I could follow was to find a temp file (txt), but my temp folder does not have any text related to Blender.

The temp folder I am checking is the one where the recovery files are present.

Is there any other way to find out why Blender crashes constantly? Sometimes after the crash, I can not even re-open  blender anymore and I need to restart Windows.

The computer I am using:
AMD Ryzen 9 5950X
128 GB RAM
RTX 3090

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As explained on [Crashes — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html#crash-log), you should try to use the cmd files to run Blender, it will write logs with explanations.

Alternatively, from [Windows — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/windows.html), you can see how to manually run Blender from the command prompt. Which has the advantage of having all Blender's output right in the command prompt even after it crashes.

If you can find errors, try to google them, people might have got the same issue before and got solutions you can try. If nothing can be dealt with, post the result here, so we might try to help you with that.

If it is definitely a bug, go to Blender → Help → Report a bug and follow the procedure. Also have a look at [Process/Bug Reports - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports).

Comment: Thank you, this is the report. I am trying to upload the report, but I can not see any "attachment" button  here .

Comment: You need to upload it somewhere, like pastebin or something. Then share the link here.