# blender 4 often crashing at startup or file opening

Tags: startup-file

I'm getting regular hangs.crashes at startup or opening of projects on the splash screen or load window - RAM seems to spike.  I have to force close and re-open Blender.  It doesn't happen every time but quite often.

Using Blender 4.02 and have tried:

- Clean re-install
- Fresh default file
- Disable & update addons
- Updated video drivers

Totally stumped how to trouble shoot this one

PC specs: AMD Ryzen 7, 32GB RAM, 3070 GPU

Comment: Hi. Does your computer meet the system requirements: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ ? Do you need to update the video card driver?

Comment: Yes, I'm above the system specs and GPU drivers all up to date. Absolutely stumped

Comment: Just a thought. Do you still have an older version of Blender on your computer? What happens when you run it? If you don't have an older version, maybe download one and see what happens with it?

Comment: I do, typically keep v3 and v2 around for testing.  Both are fine, just v4 isn't playing ball

Comment: Unfortunately, all I can say is good luck. If your OS is Windows, have you tried a zip version of 4.0.2? If you do, move the 4.0 folder from Users->AppData to somewhere, or delete it, before running Blender from the zip file. As you know, that will give you a clean start.

Comment: It could possibly be due to a third-party addon which hasn't been updated to cope with the V4 APIs. I'd try following https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249029/trying-to-identify-why-blender-3-0-crashes-constantly-guidance-appreciated which is still current in Blender 4.